# CSS3 HTML5 Cross Browser 3d flip effect on hover link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-transitions

I have placed several links on my site within a div and span tag that when hovering over them they flip in a 3d looking way to reveal a new message. [Look here and roll over the link in the first paragraph of text](http://elitedesignstudios.com/about/). It works ok but I have some questions. The revealed text is a little blurry and I cant fix it, and if I include a reveal message that is a couple characters longer then my link text it cuts it off instead of expanding it. I thought that only happened with a "overflow" declaration. Ideas Anyone?

The html:

```
<a href="/portfolio" title="View Our Portfolio" class="roll-link">
<span data-title="Check It Out ...">Our Portfolio</span></a>
```

The CSS:

```
/* ROLL LINKS */

.roll-link {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
vertical-align: top;
-webkit-perspective: 600px;
-moz-perspective: 600px;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
text-decoration:underline;
}

.roll-link:hover {
text-decoration:none;
}

.roll-link span {
display: block;
position: relative;
padding: 0 2px;
-webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.roll-link:hover span {
background: #3887be;
-webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
-moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}

.roll-link span:after {
content: attr(data-title);
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
padding: 0 2px;
color: #fff;
background: #3887be;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
-moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
}
```

EDIT: I added link to it working on my site and [here is the mark up to mess with](http://jsfiddle.net/LVFSA/). Im seeing it work in chrome, safari, and firefox all running on osx.

Comment: I'm having problems getting this code working in Chrome. I hover over the text but there is no message underneath. Can you please create a demo on one of the many code sites, for example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: But you have a overflow hidden declaration !

Comment: sorry yeah the overflow declaration was added later due to incompatibility issues I was having...my main issue was the blurry text but guess there is nothing that can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a real solution for this, but at this time, you can play with the `text-shadow` and `text-stroke` properties. ([some help for the stroke](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/)).

[Webdesignerdepot](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/) using this kind of link view also and they got the same problem as I see. Sadly, the data-title isn't true/real text, so it will be blurry always (unless browser developers do something with it), and if its longer than the real text, it will be always cut.

Comment: So basically in my understanding, generated content (CSS) doesn't create a `textNode`, that might be the reason for the rendering problems (in Firefox).
Right now just "Firefox and IE 10 will transition properties on pseudo-elements"  
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/26/css3-transitions-thank-god-specification/#a7

Comment: Current Chrome Canary (Version 29.0.1508.3 canary) doesn't support the transitions.

Comment: Yes, you understood it good, so we have to wait till browser developers do something with this...

Answer (score 2):

I made something like this with css some time back. Same properties but different settings. Hope it solves your blurring issue. Here the tutorial -  http://www.howtokickblogger.com/2012/11/post-links-hover-effect.html

Demo on jsFiddle - http://bit.ly/14AHwcc

However, there seems to be no solution for cutting of extra words on revealing.